# (Openlayers v6.15) How to get visible features , when I added the vector layer with "declutter" option?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

I added the vector layer with "declutter" option.
How can I get only visible features ?

I use `getFeaturesInExtent` on `Source` to get all the features placed in specific area.
But I can't tell which features are visible.

Comment: Try `msp.getFeaturesAtPixel()` with s large enough `hitTolerance` to cover the extent.